# MYSQL view is very slow

Tags: mysql, view, database-optimization

I have created view by joining multiple tables to avoid loading time on dynamic query. but its giving the same result by taking more time.

My system configuration is : 8GB RAM i5 Cpu and running this on MySQL 5.7.28.
Here is my query :

Reason to create this type of view is: I have generated this query using php loop. cause I need value as a column to everything should be in one view and i can easily access. in less time but not working. if you can suggest some better way to design view or avoid , generating query with help you php loop would be the best solution. 
Here is a definition of all tables.

[attribute_value](https://pastebin.com/jaJJY2qn)

[attribute](https://pastebin.com/9RNkF4Yh)

[gemstone_attribute_value](https://pastebin.com/CFyWtPBN)

[gemstone_attribute](https://pastebin.com/7GujtMfG)

[gemstone](https://pastebin.com/nSDu8EZ1)

[category](https://pastebin.com/WqqK7AY5)

[products](https://pastebin.com/RXKXG32P)

GLOBALS : https://pastebin.com/mp4cJf90

GLOBAL_VARIABLE : https://pastebin.com/Z538iku1

mysql_tuner_report : https://pastebin.com/DLbYgJ5Q

Here is mysql config variable: [config](https://www.scribd.com/document/440944969/Mysql-Config) 
First :

```
create view ring_view as  SELECT
    `p`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
    `p`.`name` AS `product_name`,
    `p`.`group_id` AS `group_id`,
    `p`.`gem_group_id` AS `gem_group_id`,
    `p`.`gem_id` AS `gem_id`,
    `p`.`sku` AS `product_sku`,
    `p`.`fake_sku` AS `fake_sku`,
    `p`.`desp` AS `product_desp`,
    `p`.`short` AS `product_short`,
    `p`.`price` AS `product_price`,
    `p`.`sale_price` AS `product_sale_price`,
    (`p`.`price` - `p`.`sale_price`) AS `product_discount`,
    `p`.`status` AS `product_status`,
    `p`.`slug` AS `product_slug`,
    `p`.`meta_title` AS `product_meta_title`,
    `p`.`meta_keywords` AS `product_meta_keywords`,
    `p`.`meta_desp` AS `product_meta_desp`,
    `p`.`metal_color` AS `metal_type`,
    `p`.`category_id` AS `category_id`,
    `pc`.`name` AS `category_name`,
    `pc`.`slug` AS `category_slug`,
    `pc`.`parent` AS `category_parent`,
    `pc`.`status` AS `category_status`,

(CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '47') THEN av.value END) AS 'at_Ring_Style_1',
(CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '51') THEN av.value END) AS 'at_Height_1',
(CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '52') THEN av.value END) AS 'at_Sizes_1',
(CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '53') THEN av.value END) AS 'at_Rhodium_Plated_1',
(CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '33') THEN av.value END) AS 'at_Shape_2',
(CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '36') THEN av.value END) AS 'at_Gemstone_2',
(CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '1') THEN av.value END) AS 'at_Ring_Style_2',
(CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '54') THEN av.value END) AS 'at_Stone_Breakdown_2',
(CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '2') THEN av.value END) AS 'at_Type_2',
(CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '41') THEN av.value END) AS 'at_Setting_2',
(CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '42') THEN av.value END) AS 'at_Rhodium_Finish_2',
(CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '48') THEN av.value END) AS 'at_Bracelet_Style_3',
(CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '37') THEN av.value END) AS 'at_Rhodium_Plated_3',
(CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '38') THEN av.value END) AS 'at_Approximate_Weight_3',
(CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '10') THEN av.value END) AS 'at_Diameter_3',
(CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '11') THEN av.value END) AS 'at_Length_3',
(CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '12') THEN av.value END) AS 'at_Enhancement_3',
(CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '14') THEN av.value END) AS 'at_Clasp_Type_3',
(CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '25') THEN av.value END) AS 'at_Chain_Length_4',
(CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '49') THEN av.value END) AS 'at_Necklace_Style_4',
(CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '15') THEN av.value END) AS 'at_Chain_Type_4',
(CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '16') THEN av.value END) AS 'at_Back_Type_5',
(CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '50') THEN av.value END) AS 'at_Earring_Style_5',
(CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '43') THEN av.value END) AS 'at_Backing_5',
(CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '44') THEN av.value END) AS 'at_Rhodium_Plated_5',
(CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '28') THEN av.value END) AS 'at_Height_8',
(
    CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '29') THEN av.value
END
) AS 'at_Band_Fit_8',
(
    CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '32') THEN av.value
END
) AS 'at_Gender_8',
(
    CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '39') THEN av.value
END
) AS 'at_Ring_Style_8',
(
    CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '40') THEN av.value
END
) AS 'at_Gemstone_8',
(
    CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '45') THEN av.value
END
) AS 'at_Gemstone_9',
(
    CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '46') THEN av.value
END
) AS 'at_Product_Type_9',
(
    CASE WHEN(av.attribute_id = '35') THEN av.value
END
) AS 'at_Style_9',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '1') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_number_of_center_cushion_amethyst_1',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '2') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_minimum_clarity_1',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '3') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_dimensions_1',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '4') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_setting_type_1',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '5') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_number_of_center_cushion_amethyst_2',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '6') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_minimum_clarity_2',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '7') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_dimensions_2',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '8') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_setting_type_2',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '9') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_number_of_center_cushion_amethyst_3',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '10') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_minimum_clarity_3',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '11') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_dimensions_3',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '12') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_setting_type_3',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '13') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_enhancement_3',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '14') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_number_of_center_cushion_amethyst_4',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '15') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_dimensions_4',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '16') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_setting_type_4',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '21') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_dimensions_6',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '22') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_setting_type_6',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '23') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_number_of_side_round_pink_tourmalines_6',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '24') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_minimum_size__6',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '25') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_number_of_center_round_garnets_6',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '26') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_number_of_center_cushion_amethyst_7',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '27') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_dimensions_7',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '28') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_setting_type_7',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '29') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_enhancement_7',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '30') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_dimensions_8',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '31') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_setting_type_8',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '32') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_enhancement_8',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '33') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_number_of_center_oval_opals_8',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '34') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_setting_type_9',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '35') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_minimum_size_9',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '36') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_minimum_number_of_side_round_topazes_9',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '37') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_setting_type_10',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '38') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_minimum_size_10',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '39') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_number_of_side_round_peridots_10',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '40') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_minimum_clarity_11',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '41') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_dimensions_11',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '42') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_setting_type_11',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '43') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_enhancement_11',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '44') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_number_of_side_oval_rubies_11',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '45') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_minimum_clarity_12',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '46') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_dimensions_12',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '47') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_setting_type_12',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '48') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_enhancement_12',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '49') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_number_of_center_emerald_sapphires_12',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '50') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_minimum_number_of_round_tanzanitescolor_12',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '51') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_setting_type_13',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '52') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_minimum_size_13',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '53') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_number_of_center_round_garnets_13',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '54') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_number_of_round_Saphire_14',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '55') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_enhancement_14',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '56') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_minimum_size_14',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '57') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_minimum_clarity_14',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '58') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_setting_type_14',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '59') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_number_of_center_cushion_madeira_citrines_15',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '60') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_enhancement_15',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '61') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_minimum_clarity_15',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '62') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_dimensions_15',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '63') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_setting_type_15',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '64') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_minimum_number_of_diamonds_16',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '65') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_total_carat_weight_16',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '66') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_average_color_16',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '67') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_average_clarity_16',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '68') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_setting_type_16',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '70') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Shape_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '71') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Color_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '72') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Clarity_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '73') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Cut_Grade_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '74') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Polish_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '75') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Symmetry_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '76') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Fluor_Intensity_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '77') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Fluor_Color_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '78') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Measurements_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '79') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Fancy_Color_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '80') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Fancy_Color_Intensity_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '81') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Fancy_Color_Overtone_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '82') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Depth_%_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '83') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Table_%_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '84') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Girdle_Min_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '85') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Girdle_Max_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '86') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Girdle_Per_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '87') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Girdle_Condition_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '88') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Culet_Size_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '89') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Culet_Condition_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '90') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Crown_Height_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '91') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Crown_Angle_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '92') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Pavilion_Depth_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '93') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Aavilion_Angle_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '94') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Shade_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '95') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Carat_Weight_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '96') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_No_of_Stones_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '97') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Setting_5',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '98') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Dimensions_1',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '99') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Dimensions_2',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '100') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Dimensions_3',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '101') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Dimensions_4',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '102') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Dimensions_6',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '103') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Dimensions_7',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '104') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Dimensions_8',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '105') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Dimensions_9',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '106') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Dimensions_10',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '107') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Dimensions_11',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '108') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Dimensions_12',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '109') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Dimensions_13',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '110') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Dimensions_14',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '111') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Dimensions_15',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '112') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Dimensions_16',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '113') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Total_Carat_Weight_1',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '114') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Total_Carat_Weight_2',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '115') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Total_Carat_Weight_3',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '116') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Total_Carat_Weight_4',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '117') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Total_Carat_Weight_6',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '118') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Total_Carat_Weight_7',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '119') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Total_Carat_Weight_8',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '120') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Total_Carat_Weight_9',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '121') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Total_Carat_Weight_10',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '122') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Total_Carat_Weight_11',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '123') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Total_Carat_Weight_12',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '124') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Total_Carat_Weight_13',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '125') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Total_Carat_Weight_14',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '126') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Total_Carat_Weight_15',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '127') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Approx._Total_Carat_Weight_16',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '128') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Quality_Grade_1',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '129') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Quality_Grade_2',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '130') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Quality_Grade_3',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '131') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Quality_Grade_4',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '132') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Quality_Grade_6',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '133') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Quality_Grade_7',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '134') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Quality_Grade_8',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '135') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Quality_Grade_9',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '136') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Quality_Grade_10',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '137') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Quality_Grade_11',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '138') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Quality_Grade_12',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '139') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Quality_Grade_13',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '140') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Quality_Grade_14',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '141') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Quality_Grade_15',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '142') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Quality_Grade_16',
(
    CASE WHEN(gv.gem_attr_id = '143') THEN gv.value
END
) AS 'gs_Stone_Breakdown_5'
FROM  products p
LEFT JOIN attribute_value av ON p.group_id = av.group_id
LEFT JOIN attribute attr ON av.attribute_id = attr.attribute_id
LEFT JOIN gemstone_attribute_value gv ON p.gem_group_id = gv.gem_group_id
LEFT JOIN gemstone_attribute gttr ON gv.gem_attr_id = gttr.gemstone_attribute_id
LEFT JOIN gemstone g ON gttr.gemstone_id = g.gemstone_id
LEFT JOIN category pc ON pc.category_id = attr.category_id
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

View taking 1.2 seconds to create but when i am trying to access using query or phpmyadmin. its taking too much time to respond. even most of the time mysql server gone. and i have to kill process from terminal.

Comment: Please post the 7 (seven) SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name;  for the 7 tables used in your view starting with products and the next 6 JOINED lines.  We will be able to verify you have indexes for both sides of the JOIN xx ON leftside = rightside.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD/NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com (NOT SCRIBD) and share the links. 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: hi @WilsonHauck i have updated with the required information. please suggest something now.

Comment: How many CPUs/COREs on your Server? Do you have HDD, SSD, NVME for data storage?  Please post TEXT results from Linux for ulimit -a for a list of limits to complete analysis.  Thanks

Comment: `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` may be useful in analyzing the slow query.  Meanwhile, the STATUS says that the machine is very idle overall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we number your view's LEFT JOINS j1-j6, consider the following observations,

attribute_value tbl has a redundant index,
ADD KEY `attribute_id` (`aval_id`),
should likely be
ADD KEY `attribute_id` (`attribute_id`),
to avoid the redundant index and be available for use in j2.

attribute tbl has
`category_id` varchar(255) default '0',
should likely be DATATYPE
`category_id` int(11) NOT NULL  ...,
for use in j6 AND add INDEX for the column.

gemstone_attribute_value tbl has
ADD KEY `gemstone_abbribute_id` (`g_aval_id`),
that would be a redundant index and likely should be DROPPED.

gemstone_attribute tbl has
`gemstone_id` varchar(255) default '0',
should likely be DATATYPE 
`gemstone_id` int(11) NOT NULL  ...,
for use in j5 AND add INDEX for the column,

Your CASE WHEN lines for gv.gem_attr_id = 'nnn' could be without the single quotes to avoid DATATYPE conversions for every compare since gem_attr_id is INT datatype and save CPU cycles.

For additional observations/suggestions, please view my profile to make contact.

Comment: @belgian-diamonds Thanks for the upvote and accepted.  Could you comment on A) original and typical current response time, B) relief from 'has gone away' and C) reduction in killing processes.  Thanks.

Comment: @belgian-diamonds You might want to correct earlier reference to MariaDB to version 5.7.28  MySQL (early in your question)  according to your posted Global Variables.